# PickerView. How do I get to move to the second component in the first movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i have PickerView with two components. I would want that the motion of the first component and the second automatic move. 
[image]

Do not offer me `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Comment: Why don't you want didSelectRow:  ? Have you tried this and it hasn't worked ?

Comment: In the end, I made ​​it through. I just want that to component 2 spinning together with component 1. thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  WPSecondViewController.h
//  test
//
//  Created by VASANTH K on 21/01/14.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WPSecondViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@end
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate` and `datasource` of picker to `viewController`.

```
//
//  WPSecondViewController.m
//  test
//
//  Created by VASANTH K on 21/01/14.
//

#import "WPSecondViewController.h"

@interface WPSecondViewController ()

@end
```

This code simple scroll the one component to  match the other component row also.

```
@implementation WPSecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 20;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",row,component];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component==0)
    {
    [self.picker selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.picker selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }


}

@end
```